# Don't work complex queries in iReport?

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

I'm working with *iReport* and I  put a table from dataset and  it has the following query( query test, because after I plan to add parameters):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT claseDocIdentidadFallecido AS DOCUMENTO,
IFNULL( (SELECT e.numRegistrosReportados FROM estadisticoRD e WHERE e.codOficina='A1B'
    AND e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido='CC' AND e.mes=8 ), 0) AS MES1,
IFNULL( (SELECT e.numRegistrosReportados FROM estadisticoRD e WHERE e.codOficina='A1B'
    AND e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido='CC' AND e.mes=9 ), 0) AS MES2,
IFNULL( (SELECT e.numRegistrosReportados FROM estadisticoRD e WHERE e.codOficina='A1B'
    AND e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido='CC' AND e.mes=10 ), 0) AS MES3
FROM estadisticoRD e WHERE e.codOficina='A1B' AND e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido='CC'
```

Well, I test it with *iReport* and It shows :

[image]

But when I try to compile and I get the following message:

`

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
      1. Field not found : claseDocIdentidadFallecido      
      2. Field not found : IFNULL( (SELECT e.numRegistrosReportados FROM estadisticoRD e WHERE e.codOficina='A1B'     AND e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido='CC' AND e.mes=8 ), 0)      
      3. Field not found : IFNULL( (SELECT e.numRegistrosReportados FROM estadisticoRD e WHERE e.codOficina='A1B'     AND e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido='CC' AND e.mes=9 ), 0)      
      4. Field not found : IFNULL( (SELECT e.numRegistrosReportados FROM estadisticoRD e WHERE e.codOficina='A1B'     AND e.claseDocIdentidadFallecido='CC' AND e.mes=10 ), 0)
      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:153)     
      at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:512)     
      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     
      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) `
```

So, what am I  doing wrong?

Comment: Why?, could you be more specific.

Comment: It is because of you are using claseDocIdentidadFallecido as a filed, you can search on the xml code otherwise post XML code of report?

Comment: Why don't you paste your query in the text field and then click on the `Read Fields` button? This way you would be able to tell if your query is working or not. Moreover, have you checked whether your query is working or not in MySQL Workbench first?

Comment: @Rachcha If you see the image I checked my query I get one register.

Comment: @Sharad I don't put nothing, all all made iReport

Answer (score 0):

You haven't field $F{claseDocIdentidadFallecido} in report.
This field named AS **DOCUMENTO**